# python -m tkinter gives me python.exe: no module named tkinter error

Tags: python, windows, python-2.7, tkinter

I need to use tkinter to create a GUI in windows 7 using python, but have hit a brick wall...

I read the offical documentation [here](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/tkinter.html) and it tells me to run the command python -m tkinter to check if the module is installed but all I get is this error message on the command line;

python.exe: No module named tkinter

I have had problems like this in the past and want to correctly install the modules this time, so one of my questions is, How do I install modules correctly? (so that python knows they are there!)

I have a cleanly installed system and have changed the environment variables to point to my python27 directory so it should work...

Can someone please help me?

If more information is required I would be happy to provide it, thanks everyone...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using python 2.7, the module name is `Tkinter`, not `tkinter`.

Answer (score 0):

But if you *are* using Python 3 (on Windows):

- try reinstalling your Python (the newer installers offer not to install parts, maybe you did previously?)

  - https://www.python.org/downloads/
- check your system paths:

  - `PATH` (https://superuser.com/questions/297947/is-there-a-convenient-way-to-edit-path-in-windows-7, I like https://patheditor2.codeplex.com/)
  - `TCL_LIBRARY` if it exists, you'll get some tkinter errors about tcl (remove/disable it)
- restart your CMD if you've changed system paths
- try again: `python -m tkinter` (PATH) or `py -m tkinter` ([launches](https://docs.python.org/3/using/windows.html#launcher) the latest installed Python)

Comment: In your first bullet point I think you meant "paths" not "parts" can you correct this?

Comment: @ChrisStone With _parts_ I meant modules (i.e. `tkinter`), currently called "software components" and "optional features" (enabled by default in 3.7 64 bit for Windows). But you have a point, since customizing the "install location" is possible as well, this might be another cause for path related issues, although this should be covered with my second bullet point. Anyway, thanks for the input.